# Exponentiate complex numbers by real numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation, complex-geometry

Exponentiation of complex numbers by complex numbers is tricky, and ultimately solved "the right way" by allowing Riemann surfaces other than $\mathbf{C}$ to be domains of the intervening functions.

If I were to exponentiate a complex number $$z = \rho\cdot e^{i\theta}$$
by a real number $t\in\mathbf{R}$, I would just set:

$$z^t := \rho^t\cdot e^{it\theta}.$$

Am I missing something or is it that simple? Is the function $z\mapsto z^t$ continuous/holomorphic? and on which domain of $\mathbf{C}$?

It sure recovers the usual exponentiation by $t$ if $z$ is real.

Thanks.

Comment: You need restrictions on $\theta$, or else you'll get contradicting results.

Comment: As $z=\rho e^{i\theta}=\rho e^{i(\theta-2\pi)}$ then is $z^t$ equal to $\rho^t e^{it\theta}$ or to $\rho^t e^{it(\theta-2\pi)}$?

Comment: You can try using the Cauchy-Riemann equations to prove whether or not the function is holomorphic.

Comment: I tried to compose an answer to this question, but I just led myself to a dead end, so here it is as a comment. I’m not sure if it will help though.

As [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html) states, if $\{a+bi,c+di\}\subset\Bbb C$ then

$$(a+bi)^{(c+di)}= \left( a^2+b^2\right) ^{ (c+id)/2}\exp\left[i(c+di)\arg(a+bi)\right]$$

Since you stated $z\in\Bbb C$ and $t\in\Bbb R$, let us reduce this to

$$z^t = (a+bi)^t = \left( a^2 + b^2 \right) ^{t/2}\exp\left[ it\arg(a+bi)\right]$$

and letting $X=a^2+b^2$ compact this into

$$X^{t/2}e^{it\arg z}$$